# how to modify my kmeans function to take multivariate data?

Tags: r, algorithm, k-means

I am new to R and working on writing my own k means function as per algorithm listed in the book "Information theory, inference and learning algorithms by David Mackay" . My attempt is as follows. This function takes 1 dimensional data. How do I modify this question for multivariate data (data with more than 1 feature vector) ? Any hints on that will help. Thanks in advance.

```
######generate data#####
x<-c(rnorm(500, 4,2), rnorm(500,5,1.5),rnorm(300,1,0.5))
data<-as.data.frame(x)
d_scaled<-as.data.frame(scale(data))

#### Kmeans algorithm ########

##### calculates the euclidean distance between two points p and q

    getEuclid_dist <- function(p,q) {
  dist <- 0.5*sum((p-q)^2) 
  return(dist)
}

##### finds the nearest mean to datapoints out of the set of means

get_nearest_mean <- function(data, means) {
  nmeans <- length(means$x)
  dist <- rep(NA,nmeans)
  for (k in 1:nmeans) {
    dist[k] <- getEuclid_dist(data,means$x[k])
  }
  minval <- which(dist %in% sort(dist)[1])
 return(minval)
}

mykmeans <- function( data, k ) {
  nd <- length(data$x)   # gets  total number of datapoints

  # 1. set each mean randomly to one of the datapoints

  m <- sample(1:nd,k)
  means <- list(x=data$x[m])
  mprev <- means

  # set initial responsibilities to 1
  # col = datapoints nd
  # row =  cluster
  # r(k,nd)=1 if it's in that cluster

  rold <- matrix(0,k,nd)
  rcurr <- matrix(1,k,nd)

  #2.  loop until the responsibilities have not changed

  while (!all(rcurr==rold)) {
    rold <- rcurr
    rcurr <- matrix(0,k,nd)

    #3. assignment step

    for( n in 1:nd) {
      kn <- get_nearest_mean(data$x[n],means)
      rcurr[kn,n] <- 1
    }

    # 4. recalculate the means

    for( nk in 1:k) {
      currx <- data$x[rcurr[nk,]==1]
      if (length(currx)!=0) {
        means$x[nk] <- mean(currx)
      }
     return(list(means$x, rcurr))

    }


  }
}
clusobj<-mykmeans(data=d_scaled,k=3)
```

Comment: Soft K means or Fuzzy C means are different clustering algorithms. Regular k means assigns a data point to 1 cluster. Soft K means assigns a data points to more than 1 cluster with different probabilities. So the assignment function (responsibilities) will be slightly different rest of  the code will remain same.  My code here can take only 1 D data. The  question is how to extend my code to take care of data that is in higher dimension say R^2 or R^3 (in general any R^d where d >1).

Comment: Yes.I do not want to use the existing implementation. Since I am learning R   and also reading this book.  I want to translate the given pseudo code to write my own functions. I understand things better if I do it myself.

Comment: Then good luck in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: My code is regular Kmeans algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the point. Maybe someone else can understand why you are trying to do this. Good luck.